# Android Wear Intent.putExtra for several pages with contentAction

Tags: android-intent, for-loop, android-notifications, wear-os

I'm sending a notification with several pages from my wearable app. For each datamapItem there is a seperate page which includes an contentAction. The content Action calls a new Activity and commits an "id" from the datamapitem. This "id" should be displayed in the new Activity

ListenerService which creates notification:

```
for (int i=dataMapItem.getDataMap().size()-1; i>=0; i--) {

                ...

                Intent detailIntent =  new Intent(this, DetailActivity.class);
                detailIntent.putExtra(DetailActivity.EXTRA_ID, id);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                        detailIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                Notification.Action action = new Notification.Action(R.drawable.btn_blue_small, "open", pendingIntent);

                actions.add(action);

                if(i!=0) {
                    Notification notificationPage = new Notification.Builder(this)
                            .setContentTitle(title)
                            .setContentText(text)
                            .extend(new Notification.WearableExtender()
                                            .setBackground(colorBitmap)
                                            .setContentAction(i)
                            )
                            .build();

                    pages.add(notificationPage);

                } else {
                    Notification.Builder notificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(this)
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                            .setContentTitle(title)
                            .setContentText(text)
                            .extend(new Notification.WearableExtender()
                                            .addActions(actions)
                                            .addPages(pages)
                                            .setContentAction(i)
                                            .setBackground(colorBitmap)
                                            .setHintHideIcon(true)
                            );

                    Notification notification = notificationBuilder.build();
                    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;

                    ((NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE))
                            .notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
                }

            }
```

SecondActivity which should display the data commited via intent.putextra()

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

    mTextid = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtid);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if(intent != null) {
        id = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_ID);

    ...
}
```

So here is my problem:
because the Key for my putExtra is static, the value is overwritten in each run through the loop. And the Displayed id in the secondactiviy is always 0, or the value from the last run-through.

I hope I descriped this understandable ;)
Do anyone have a solution for this problem? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it by myself. Itw as just a silly error.
if someone cares, the was just a wrong parameter from the pending intent.

it should be:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, index,
                detailIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

instead of:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                    detailIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```